# when should you recompile a program that was manually compiled?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, libraries

I'm currently running Ubuntu Trusty and I have a few programs that are manually compiled for various reasons. I also occasionally run apt-get update && apt-get upgrade as well mainly for security reasons.

After running apt-get upgrade, when would I need to recompile programs that weren't installing using apt-get and manually compiled?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? "Whenever a new version is released with a bugfix/feature you want?"

Comment: they will have you suffer a lot. I am not one of them:)

Comment: basically trying to avoid bugs and understand when a program needs to be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

> when would I need to recompile programs that weren't installing using apt-get and manually compiled?

If your programs are linked against shared libraries, then you do *not* need to rebuild them: a bug fix in the shared library is *automatically* propagated to all future executions of every program that depends on that shared library (this is one of the major advantages of using shared libraries).

If your programs are linked against archive versions, then you must relink them to pick up the bug fixes.